# Find text between key phrases

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I have a var that have some text in:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="foo">
element.password_input=
<div class="holder">
<label for="$${input_id}" > $${label_text}</label>
<input name="$${input_name}" id="$${input_id}" value="$${input_value}" type="password" />
</div>
# END element.password_input
element.text_input=
<div class="ctrlHolder">
<label for="$${element_id}" > $${element_label_text}</label>
<input name="$${element_name}" id="$${element_id}" 
value="$${element_value}" type="text" 
class="textInput"  />
</div>
# END element.text_input
</cfsavecontent>
```

and I am trying to parse through the var to get all of the different element type(s) here is what I have so far:

```
ar = REMatch( "element\.+(.*=)(.*?)*", foo )
```

but it is only giving me  this part:

```
element.text_input=
element.password_input=
```

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your immediate problem is that by default `.` doesn't include newlines - you would need to use the flag `(?s)` in your regex for it to do this.

However, simply enabling that flag still wont result in your present regex doing what you're expecting it to do.

A better regex would be:

```
(element\.\w+)=(?:[^##]+|##(?! END \1))+(?=## END \1)
```

You would then do `ListFirst(match[i],'=')` and `ListRest(match[i],'=')` to get the name and value. (rematch doesn't return captured groups).

<sup>(Obviously the #s above are doubled to escape them for CF.)</sup>

The above regex dissected is:

```
(element\.\w+)=
```

*Match `element.` and any alphanumeric, placed it into capture group 1, then match `=` character.*

```
(?:
    [^##]+
|
    ##(?! END \1)
)+
```

*Match any number of non-hash characters, or a hash not followed by the ending token (using negative lookahead `(?!...)`) and referencing capture group 1 (`\1`), repeat as many times as possible (`+`), using a non-capturing group (`(?:...)`).*

```
(?=## END \1)
```

*Lookahead `(?=...)` to confirm the variable's ending token is present.*